# Copying an existing funnel in Mixpanel and modify steps

Tags: mixpanel

I have created a funnel in mixpanel for a certain flow in my project and there are about 8-10 steps which consists of custom events.

There is a necessity that I have to duplicate the funnel and tweak 2-3 steps by changing the custom events. I have searched in mixpanel and I don't see an option to do save-as and change the steps. It is time consuming process to create the funnel every time with the same steps.

So, I wanted to know if anyone have faced this issue and found out a solution for this?

I have gone through the below link while searching for solution and found no solution,

[Import funnels (structure) between projects (not data)](http://community.mixpanel.com/t/import-funnels-structure-between-projects-not-data/356)